# Words being broken unnecessarily in table columns in Documentation topics

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, design

Text inside tables in SO Documentation topics such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jekyll/3756/front-matter/14814/predefined-variables#t=201702202044137104345) is being wrapped mid-word when doing so is obviously unnecessary.

Example:

[image]

It's clear that in the above table the right column could be shrunk to avoid breaking in the middle of words in the first column.

As it stands, column one is completely unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this! I added a couple CSS rules to `<code>` blocks inside markdown `<table>`s within docs. Obviously this is not a bulletproof fix, though in spot checking a number of popular topics, I didn't find any obvious breakages after applying these rules.

[image]

If anyone sees a table with `<code>` blocks that breaks or looks off, please let us know here or elsewhere on Meta.

Thanks again for reporting!

Comment: Great work! Thanks for making this happen.